# How to Remove White Screen after Splash Screen in React Native For Android

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I have a default react native project I installed from this [turorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) and I added a splash screen to my Project with [this tutorial](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae). However, now I get:

- a 0.5 secend splash screen photo
- then 1.5 secend white screen
- and after that my app started,

**What is the best and most standard way to fix this problem?** 
I need my splash screen for 1 secend and after that my app should start,
I have read more articles but I couldn't find a fix for react native.

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:**
Run `npm i react-native-splash-screen --save`

**Second step(Plugin Installation):**
**Automatic installation**

```
react-native link react-native-splash-screen or rnpm link react-native-splash-screen
```

**Manual installation**
**Android:**
1: In your `android/settings.gradle` file, make the following additions:

```
include ':react-native-splash-screen'   
project(':react-native-splash-screen').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/android')
```

2: In your android/app/build.gradle file, add the `:react-native-splash-screen` project as a compile-time dependency:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
}
```

3: Update the MainApplication.java file to use `react-native-splash-screen` via the following changes:

```
// react-native-splash-screen >= 0.3.1
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;
// react-native-splash-screen < 0.3.1
import com.cboy.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        protected boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
            return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                    new MainReactPackage(),
            new SplashScreenReactPackage()  //here
            );
        }
    };

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }
}
```

**Example Code:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Linking,
} from 'react-native'
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

export default class example extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.container}
                onPress={(e)=> {
                    Linking.openURL('http://www.devio.org/');
                }}
            >
                <View >
                    <Text style={styles.item}>
                        SplashScreen 启动屏
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.item}>
                        @：http://www.devio.org/
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.item}>
                        GitHub:https://github.com/crazycodeboy
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.item}>
                        Email:crazycodeboy@gmail.com
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#f3f2f2',
        marginTop: 30
    },
    item: {
        fontSize: 20,
    },
    line: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 0.3,
        backgroundColor: 'darkgray',
    },
})
```

Comment: I’ve tried to use this library twice. It’s [riddled with issues](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues) and seems to just break builds. I think it’s probably due to the moving-target nature of React Native and Android/iOS environments.

Answer (score 13):

I fix this by following steps mentioned by [**@sergiulucaci on GitHub**](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/338) like this and it worked

> Go to **android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml**

**Disable the app's preview as follows:**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item> // <--- ADD THIS
        // Other items...
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 12):

I too have been through this problem. In my case it was redux persist library that use to extract persisted state from storage and feed it into the reducers and this process use to take almost 1 second during that second it used to show white screen a little flicker and then it renders the actual screen.

The work around i used is this actually the control to hide splash is on javascript side you are doing this to hide it.

```
componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide();
}
```

Just add a little delay and it will work fine.

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => SplashScreen.hide() , 2000);
}
```

Comment: ReferrenceError: Can't find variable SplashScreen

Comment: @Sam You got to use [react-native-splash-screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen)

Comment: This `setTimeout` worked for me, I use it with 500ms instead.
This solution seems a little ugly for me, but I couldn't find anything else to resolve it appropriately

Answer (score 12):

### This was my solution for IOS - 2021 on RN v.063

from the React Native documents
https://reactnative.dev/docs/publishing-to-app-store#pro-tips

1. Search and find your `AppDelegate.m` file
2. Add this code
3. Re-build the app (so stop the app and start it again)

```
// Place this code after "[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]" and before "return YES;"
  UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LaunchScreen" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
  rootView.loadingView = vc.view;
```

### here is the React Native docs message

As your App Bundle grows in size, you may start to see a blank screen flash between your splash screen and the display of your root application view. If this is the case, you can add the following code to `AppDelegate.m` in order to keep your splash screen displayed during the transition.

Comment: Link to React Native docs where it says this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/publishing-to-app-store#pro-tips

Comment: That code snippet doesn't make sense today in 2024 sigh.

Comment: @EricBloch, were you able to figure something out?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution for both ios and android: https://github.com/mehcode/rn-splash-screen.
I hid the splash screen in the render function of my app.tsx (the entry point) and showed the same image until all of my https requests were done.

My code:

```
public render()
    {
        SplashScreen.hide();

       //after everything has finished loading - show my app.
       if (this.state.isFinishedloading) 
        {
            return (
                <this.navigator screenProps={{ ...providers }} />
            );
        }

      // Until then show the same image as the splash screen with an ActivityIndicator.
        return (
           <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/img/splash.png')} >
                <ActivityIndicator  style={styles.indicator} color="#fff"></ActivityIndicator>
              </Image>
           </View>
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I met this issue(RN v0.62.2, iPhone), I could resolve it by following React Native official document though.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#2-configure-release-scheme

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue, spent lots of time in debugging.

Solution: CSS property was duplicating in one of my components. Removing duplication fixed white screen issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this issue.

Changing splash screen background color to the one which I use on the next screen saved the situation for both platforms

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Linking,
} from 'react-native'
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

export default class App extends Component {

    async componentDidMount() {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.container}
                onPress={(e)=> {
                    Linking.openURL('http://www.devio.org/');
                }}
            >
                <View >
                    <Text style={styles.item}>
                        SplashScreen 启动屏
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.item}>
                        @：http://www.devio.org/
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.item}>
                        GitHub:https://github.com/crazycodeboy
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.item}>
                        Email:crazycodeboy@gmail.com
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#f3f2f2',
        marginTop: 30
    },
    item: {
        fontSize: 20,
    },
    line: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 0.3,
        backgroundColor: 'darkgray',
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**For iOS**

```
  UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LaunchScreen" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
  UIView* launchScreenView = vc.view;
  launchScreenView.frame = self.window.bounds;
  rootView.loadingView = launchScreenView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for android by making the color of the white screen the same as the color of the splash screen.

Comment: @James Risner I wrote but no one cared. Those who knew too much immediately lost.

Comment: Please keep the part where you ask something out of your answering post. And I think you need to review what is left to make sure that it is perceived as an answer to the question at the top of the page.