# How to remove white flashes on react-native app on Android?

Tags: react-native

When my app is launching I can see a brief white flash when screens are changing. I have a dark theme app so it's pretty annoying to see those flashes.

I have found react-native-flash-screen module which could help me (install, link, edit MainActivity.java, import to App.js) but after installing of it my app goes to loop of rebooting.

Does someone know how to prevent white flashes, probably, on another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Remove White Screen after Splash Screen in React Native For Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384491/how-to-remove-white-screen-after-splash-screen-in-react-native-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

it's hard question because I have not seen your code 
but 
wrap your app container with a view and style that backgroundColor to black
this might help your