# White screen shows after Splash Screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-splash-screen

in React Native, a white screen appears after the Splash Screen. The white screen is briefly displayed, and then the application screen opens. What is the reason for this? I want to solve this problem without using a package. How can I solve this problem?

I don't understand what kind of mental illness the detractors are. Most solutions are out of date and use packages!

Comment: first of all what do you use for displaying splash screen ? `react-native-splash-screen` or r`eact-native-bootsplash`, could you provide some code at least?

Comment: @Hamed I used react-native-bootsplash in my old project. Now I started a new project and I don't want to use packages in this project. I want to solve this problem without using packages. I just created the project and didn't write any code.

Comment: the only way to do it by writing native code on ios and android.
see this article here

https://medium.com/@rfontes/splash-screens-on-react-native-without-libs-b487d08264ee

Comment: @Hamed 1/2 This article explains how to make the Splash Screen with native. I have no problem with creating Splash Screen. I'm already doing this.

Comment: @Hamed 2/2 A white screen is shown after the Splash Screen is shown. I want to solve this white screen issue.

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384491/how-to-remove-white-screen-after-splash-screen-in-react-native-for-android
maybe this could help

Comment: @Hamed Yes, I implemented the answers  but it didn't work. It's probably no longer up to date. Many have already made package suggestions.